# Run promises sequentially with Promise.all and a map function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I've been trying to use a batched array and fire requests sequentially using `Promise.all` and a map function:

```js
const slowAsync = (i) => {
  return setTimeout(() => {
     return Promise.resolve(i);
  }, 1000)
}

const batchedIds = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]];

batchedIds.map(async batch => {
  const response = await Promise.all(batch.map(id => {
    return slowAsync(id);
  }));
  
  console.log(response);
})
```

Right now the console logs everything at once

```sh
//after 1 second
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
```

but I want it to log each resolve of the promise with 1 second difference

```sh
//after 1 second
[1, 2]
//after 1 second
[3, 4]
//after 1 second
[5, 6]
```

Is it possible to do this without recursion or libraries and by using a map function?

Comment: I think that Promise.all inherently does the opposite of what you want, e.g. waits until all of the promises are resolved. You can do this sequentially with an await inside a loop.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `.map()` on your `batchedIds` array if you're not going to use the array the `.map()` creates for you, for that there is `.forEach()` - but both `.map()` and `.forEach()` don't await their asynchronous callbacks before proceeding to the next iteration, so if you want sequential behavior you can use a for..of loop with `await` (see: [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787))

Comment: thank you @NickParsons that was exactly my problem in my actual code, thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `slowAsync` function is not correctly implemented. Returning something inside a `setTimeout` callback has no effect. And `setTimeout` itself returns a numerical identifier, not a promise.

Secondly, you should replace your `.map()` iteration with a `for` loop, and wrap all that in an `async` function so you can use `await`.

Here is the correction:

```js
const slowAsync = (i) => new Promise(resolve =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve(i), 1000)
);

const batchedIds = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]];

(async () => {
  for (const batch of batchedIds) {
    const response = await Promise.all(batch.map(id => {
      return slowAsync(id);
    }));
    console.log(response);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Trincot got it in a nutshell!

As a further remark: Instead of using a function closure you could also use `Function.prototype.bind()` to bind the individual `id`s of each batch to the `setTimeout()` callback-function like shown below:

```js
const batchedIds = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6],[7,8,9,10]];

(async () => {
  for (const batch of batchedIds) {
    console.log(await Promise.all(batch.map(id=>new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r.bind(null,id),1000)))));
  }
})();
```